# Unable to bind to server: Not Supported when doing ldap_sasl_bind()

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, sasl

I am trying to connect and bind to an AD using `ldap_sasl_bind()` but I get:

`warning: 2 :: ldap_sasl_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Not Supported`

I have confirmed using `ldapsearch` I can connect and get users from AD using a kerberos ticket stored using a keytab with `kinit`. I have also confirmed $KRB5CCNAME env variable has the correct cache path `FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_501`.

I have no idea what else I could try and since documentation and resources about PHP and LDAP/SASL is almost inexistent I would like to know if anybody else has faced an similar issue or if somebody has configured AD with SASL and connected from PHP successfully.

The PHP code:

```
$a = ldap_connect("ldap://ad.azure.com:389");
if (!$a) {
    die("cant connect!");
}
$b = ldap_sasl_bind($a, null, null, 'GSSAPI');
if (!$b) {
    die("SASL failed");
}

echo "CONNECTED";
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out:

`ldap_set_option($a, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);`

Before calling bind.